# TextBox Customization

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, customization

how can I customize my textbox like in the Picture ?

[image: TextBox]

Comment: Can you? Did you try? What did you try? What issue you are facing?

Comment: sorry for posting like this can you click the link to see the picture, im new in stackoverflow sorry

Comment: You need to explain what application type it is? Web application or Windows application? You need to search online about this and try something. And ask question here if you are facing any issue. Basic logic is you need to figure out how can you change background color, fonts, border size, border color etc of textbox.

Comment: im using windows application i already search but can't find something helpful, that's why i post here i can't find something or anyone can help

Comment: http://csharp.net-informations.com/gui/cs-textbox.htm

Comment: i already read that bro . did you see the picture ?

Comment: What's the confusion? I see the picture... You can achieve that by setting various properties of Textbox. What you don't understand about setting the properties of the TextBox? You want me to explain what property you need to set to what value to get the textbox you wanted?

Comment: dont be harsh on me bro im new in c# im new in visual studio i know i want spoon feed thats why i want what i want to achieve in the textbox

Comment: Spoon feeding does not make you learn. I given you the hints about how you can do it. If you are completely unfamiliar with Visual Studio, .NET, Windows From application then you should start learning basics of it. Directly jumping creating something complex without basic knowledge will get you confused and you will end up asking many more questions like this. You will not get spoon fed on SO for sure. So start learning basics first.

Answer (score 0):

xaml

```
   <TextBox BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="Gray" Background="Transparent" GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus" LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus"/>
```

c#

```
   private void TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
      var tb = (TextBox)sender;
      tb.BorderBrush = Brushes.Black;
      tb.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 2);
   }

   private void TextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
      var tb = (TextBox)sender;
      tb.BorderBrush = Brushes.Gray;
      tb.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 1);
   }
```